# Show loader while component is loading

Tags: vue.js

I am working on a Vue app where we have one Vue instance that extends several other components.

```
//import <Loader/>

const componentOne = Vue.extend({
    mounted: function() { this.$root.$data.componentOneLoading = false  }
    //...options
});

const componentTwo = componentOne.extend({ //...options })
Vue.component('component-two', componentTwo);

Loader.extend(componentOne);

const vm = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     componentOneLoading: false
   },
   methods: {
      toogleComponentOne: function() {
        this.componentOneLoading = true;
      }
   },
   components: {
     componentOne
   }
});
```

The problem I have right now is in the HTML, when the `toogleComponentOne` method is called, the component will show but it will sometime take a couple of seconds to show. I want to display a loading screen during this time. With the way our app is set up, if I use the property `componentOneLoading` to show either the `Loading` component or `componentOne/componentTwo`, it will not work, because `componentOne/componentTwo` never gets mounted and I cannot use life cycle methods such as `mounted` to change `this.$root.$data.componentOneLoading = false`, since it `Loader` component will be mounted.

```
<div id='#app'>
   <button @click="toogleComponentOne()"
   <component-two v-if="componentOneLoading = false"></component-two>
   <loader v-else></loader> //Since componentOneLoading is set to true on event click, this will get mounted and component-two will never mount and I cant use lifecycle hooks to set it to false.
</div>
```

This is the same even if I wrap it in divs.

```
<div id='#app'> 
   <button @click="toogleComponentOne()"
   <div  v-if="componentOneLoading = false">
      <component-two></component-two>
   </div>
   <div v-else>
      <loader v-else></loader>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried passing in props to `componentOne/componentTwo` and inside these component's template use the `v-if` but this doesnt seem to work. I have to do the condition outside. How can I show `Loader` until `componentOne/componentTwo` is finished loading and ready to render?

Answer (score 0):

you can emit  a custom event when `component-two` is mounted and upon that you swtich `componentOneLoading` with an event listener and use `v-show` instead of `v-if` to make sure you element exists on the DOM:

```js
//componentTwo.vue
mounted : {
 ...
 this.$emit('toggleLoading')
}
```

```html
<!-- App.vue / root component -->
<div  v-show="!componentOneLoading">
   <component-two @toggleLoading="componentOneLoading = !componentOneLoading "></component-two>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this will work. In order for `mounted` to get invoked, `componentTwo` needs to get mounted, but as you can see in my HTML, the `@click` event sets a boolean to true and this will show the Loader component, never giving the componenTwo to mount and do `mounted()`